# Aggregated Materialized View

Tags: clickhouse

I am bulding a KPI viewer where I have to show certain aggregated values over a period of 5-6 years. As I am fairly new to CH, I rely heavily on reading the documentation but sometimes lack to find examples.

```
CREATE TABLE test1.table1
(
    seriesId Int32,
    amount Int64, 
    txt varchar(100)
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
order by (seriesId)
;
```

Now the goal is to get a materialized view that does

1. sum of all amounts in a series
2. count (distinct) of all amounts in the series
3. min (amount)
4. max (amount)

i have figured out how to use SummingMergeTree to solve the SUM and count part (if I create a seprate View just for those 2 aggregated values), but I am not able to figure out the min and max. Every solution, I get has duplicates on the view. For SummingMergeTree, there might be duplicates as well **but they eventually get merged** but for aggregatingMergeTree, I don't seem to be able to get them merged.

The raw table has aprox. 4 Billion rows

my attempt was to do it like that

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test1.MV1
ENGINE=AggregatingMergeTree() 
ORDER BY seriesId
POPULATE
AS 
SELECT  
    seriesId ,
    sum(amount) as amt ,
    min(amount) as minAmt,
    max(amount) as maxAmt
from test1.table1 t 
group by seriesId
```

Now that does not work as I was hoping it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test1.MV1
(
  seriesId Int32,
  sumAmt SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, Int64),
  minAmt SimpleAggregateFunction(min, Int64),
  maxAmt SimpleAggregateFunction(max, Int64),
  uniqAmt AggregateFunction(uniqExact, Int64)
)
ENGINE=AggregatingMergeTree() 
ORDER BY seriesId 
AS 
SELECT  
    seriesId ,
    sum(amount) sumAmt,
    min(amount) minAmt,
    max(amount) maxAmt,
    uniqExactState(amount) uniqAmt
from test1.table1 t 
group by seriesId
```

```sql
select seriesId, sum(sumAmt), min(minAmt), max(maxAmt), uniqExactMerge(uniqAmt)
from test1.MV1
/* where seriesId = ..  */
group by seriesId
```

---

- consider using [uniqCombined](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/uniqcombined/) instead of [uniqExact](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/uniqexact/#agg_function-uniqexact) to optimize memory consumption

Comment: hi, I have run again into a similar issue but it seems that it does not aggregate well. If I have a table that has incremental inserts lets say 20x a day and i want the account balance (financial) to be aggregated over all those transaction inserts, i am not getting the right values.